# Synchronizing SQLite DB on Linux using Sync Framework

Tags: linux, sqlite, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I need to synchronize a SQLite Database on Linux platform using the Microsoft sync framework.

I have built sample sync applications on Windows platform but Linux is a problem. Any ideas ?

Comment: have you seen this other thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422903/books-links-samples-on-microsoft-sync-framework-for-sqlite-sync-with-sql-2008

Comment: Yeagh I have checdked it